# jQuery, foreach div in ul

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How I can do a `foreach` or similar in jQuery? I need that when the user clicks in the `<span>`, add the class `inactive` to all `<div>`s with the `vote active` class in the `<ul>`.

I've tried with the `.each` method, but it doesn't work.

I have this HTML:

```
<ul class="suggestions inactive">
    <li id="s2">
        <div class="id">2</div>
        <div class="vote inactive">
            <span class="up"></span>
            <span class="down"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">test2</div>
        <div class="rating">2</div>
    </li>
    <li id="s3">
        <div class="id">3</div>
        <div class="vote active">
            <span class="up"></span>
            <span class="down"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">test3</div>
        <div class="rating">0</div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

And this script:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){

                var ul = $('ul.suggestions');

                // Listening of a click on a UP or DOWN arrow:

                $('div.vote span').live('click',function(){

                    var elem        = $(this),
                        parent      = elem.parent(),
                        li          = elem.closest('li'),
                        ratingDiv   = li.find('.rating'),
                        id          = li.attr('id').replace('s',''),
                        v           = 1,
                        ul2         = elem.closest('li').parent();

                    // If the user's already voted:
                    if(parent.hasClass('inactive')){
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(ul2.hasClass('inactive')){           
                        return false;
                    }

                    //If the user's already voted, add following class
                    parent.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');                                  
                    ul2.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');


                    if(elem.hasClass('down')){
                        v = -1;
                    }

                    // Incrementing the counter on the right:
                    ratingDiv.text(v + +ratingDiv.text());

                    // Turning all the LI elements into an array
                    // and sorting it on the number of votes:

                    var arr = $.makeArray(ul.find('li')).sort(function(l,r){
                        return +$('.rating',r).text() - +$('.rating',l).text();
                    });

                    // Adding the sorted LIs to the UL
                    ul.html(arr);

                    // Sending an AJAX request
                    $.get('ajax.php',{action:'vote',vote:v,'id':id});
                });
```

Comment: Say something more about your problem. "Does not work" does not help.

Comment: Maybe i dont know how implement the .each method...

Comment: There is one wonderful solution to that problem - the [documentation of `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) with multiple examples.

Comment: @Sid You don't need `.each()`. See my answer on why.

Comment: I dont know how implement with that code for something i came here, but thanks, i've already read that, but honestly, thank you again. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `.each()` here at all.

Why? Because jQuery's selectors wonderfully select everything of a single selector type. `$('p')` selects *every* `p` in your HTML.

**You should use**

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');`
```

from within the scope of the

```
$('div.vote span').live('click',function() { ... } );
```

Also, remember that `.live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+.

Comment: That worked more or less, thanks.  And what must use instead of live?

Comment: @Sid You're welcome. Be sure to upvote/accept. Instead of `.live()`, you should use `$(document).on('click', 'div.vote span', function() {...});`

Comment: @Sid Btw, it looks like you're new to SO. You can click the checkmark to accept this answer.

Comment: OK! yes , im new here , y checked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you really want to add that class to ALL elements in the HTML?  If so, I guess I would just do this:

```
$("div").addClass("inactive");
```

Comment: This works for ALL the div elements, not what i need, but works with all div, so thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `each` for adding class to multiple elements. Just select them and apply `addClass()`:

```
jQuery('div.vote.active').addClass('inactive');
```

If you insist on using `.each()`, then it really **works**. Just use it properly:

```
jQuery('div.vote.active').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('inactive');
});
```

Did it help?